# Are the indices in $\Sigma_j A_{ji}e_j$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

A lot of times when I see a matrix-vector multiplication written in index form, it seems like the dimensions of the matrix are inverted or that the index they are using for the vector is the wrong one. I have seen this in many courses, but its never clear.

In my lecture notes for instance as part of a larger proof, they start like this:

> Let $\{e_1,e_2,...e_n \}$ be an orthonormal basis of $V$ and $f:V\mapsto V $
> an endormorphism. Let $A$ be the matrix representing the
> endomorphism in this basis.
>
> The columns of the matrix are: $f(e_i)=\Sigma_j A_{ji}e_j$

They didn't say it explicitly but I am pretty sure they are using column vectors as it is standard in linear algebra. So if the bases have $n$ elements I expect the matrix to be a $n\times n$ matrix, and therefore if the matrix $A$ is indexed as $A_{ji}$, $e$ should be indexed with $i=i\times1$ and not with $j$ as they are doing, that is I expect

$$f(e_i)=\sum_i A_{ji}e_i$$ or $$f(e_j)=\sum_j A_{ij}e_j$$

I don't think is a typo since they use it everywhere.

**Could it be that I am unaware of some common usage?** Could it be that they just don't care about the vector being a row or a column all the time and thus when they  write $\Sigma_j A_{ji}e_k$ with either $k=i$ or $k=j$   the vector $e_k$ is supposed  to be whatever it needs to be to make the expresion meaningful ( that is a column vector if they are using $j$ or  a row vector if they are using $i$) ?

Note: I found this hand-out: [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Courses/443-2013/bilinear.pdfwhich](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Courses/443-2013/bilinear.pdfwhich) is actually about the bilinear forms which is the context of my question and they do the same again, right from the first equation

$$A\mathbf{x}_j=\sum_{i=1}^nA_{ij}\mathbf{x}_j$$

Comment: The textbook is actually correct. Note that the $f(e_i)$ are each column vectors. Together (all n of them) they form a matrix. You should write out a 4 x 4 example to convince yourself.

Comment: I do not think you have given enough context here. You don't say what $V$ is, and that matters. For the statement "the columns of the matrix are $f(e_i)$" to make any sense the vector space $V$ must be the space of column vectors. But of course there are many other vector spaces, and normally $f(e_i)$ is just a member of $V$ - but the columns of the matrix still exist, and the $j$-th one is $A_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation is correct. In the equation
$$
Ax_j=\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ij}x_i\tag1
$$
the $i$ is an index of summation, whereas $j$ is "unbound". When the summation on the RHS is performed, the index $i$ disappears and the result (the RHS) involves $j$ only, same as the LHS.  If the index of summation in (1) were $j$ instead of $i$, the RHS would depend on $i$ after the dust settles, whereas the LHS would depend on $j$, which wouldn't make sense. (In fact if the index of summation in (1) were $j$ instead of $i$, we'd be able to factor out $x_i$ from the sum.)

In other words, the *specific* $x_j$ on the LHS is not the same as the *generic* $x_i$ on the RHS. In the RHS as $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n$ we visit all vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, whereas in the LHS we stay with the specific vector $x_j$.

You should interpret (1) as a statement that holds for each $j$, i.e., it's an *identity* in $j$.

Comment: Let me state better what is my problem : For instance when I multiply a mxn matrix times a nxp matrix I write in index notation as $\Sigma_k A_{ik}B{kj}$, so dimensions agree, If instead of B, I have a column vector $\Sigma_k A_{ik}v_{k1}=\Sigma_k A_{ik}v_{k}$  where the index of the vector has to be equal to the SECOND index of the matrix.  So why are they not using the second index of the matrix in the expression above? It would only make sense if x would be a row vector: $xA=\Sigma_k v{i}A_{ik}$, but we are using column vectors!

Comment: Yes, the usual convention is to make the subscripts line up when doing matrix multiplication [as is true in equation (1)]. Without additional context, I can't explain why they are writing $A_{ji}$ instead of $A_{ij}$ (if that's your question). It could be truly a typo, or maybe some convention that the coefficients need to laid out in row fashion (as if we are looking at $A^T$ instead of $A$). To avoid ambiguity, it's always best for authors to spell out the notation /convention when they introduce a matrix.

Comment: My question is that why is equation (1) correct? when you do  (matrix )x(column vector) multiplication in that order, you should sum over the column index of the matrix. Instead, they are summing over the row index of the matrix, and that would only make sense if it were a (row-vector) x (matrix)

Comment: I think I see the issue. Look at the next equation in that PDF: $A\left(\sum_j v_jx_j\right)=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}v_jx_i$. Since $\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}v_jx_i=\sum_i\left(\sum_j A_{ij}v_j\right)x_i$, the equation for the **coefficents wrt the basis** is $w_i =\sum_jA_{ij}v_j$, which follows convention and is not backwards. The notation in (1) was chosen to make the next equation follow convention.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "literal" answer, but a sort of "meta-answer".

These indexing issues with matrices are an ever-recurring source of trouble.

Part of the problem is that these indexing things are not truly intrinsic, but only some sort of fallout from notational choices *and* conventions about the language involved.

Some decades ago, I did think there'd be some underlying *ground* about order of indices... but, after working hard to get down to it, found that the true answer is/was that the problem is not about mathematics, not even quite about "normal language", but about very volatile conventions of notation.

So, my serious advice to you is to re-appraise each situation...

Comment: Is it common to start a theory saying they are going to use column vector and then suddenly writing something that seems to imply that the vector should be a row vector, without using a transpose?